# Why can't I get "res" object console logged inside the callback of app.listen in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, callback, listen

```
const http = require('http') 
const server = http.createServer(()=>{
            console.log("created server")
        });
const port = 3000;
server.listen(port, (req,res) => {console.log(res)})
```

// in console => undefined

//after opening the page => in console => created server

// no res obj in console

**why can't "res" be consolelogged even after "created server" is console logged and "http://localhost:3000" is opened too?**

Comment: Because that simply isn't how the `http` module works.

The callback passed to `createServer` gets called when the server receives a request.

The callack passed to `listen` gets called when the server starts.

You only get a request object passed to the former, because that is the callback for requests! 

You got the callbacks backwards. Voting to close as off-topic because it is a trivial error on par with a typo.

Comment: "The callback passed to listen gets called when the server starts.  "  ---- now it makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> why can't "res" be consolelogged even after "created server" is console logged

The callback to `server.listen()` just tells you when your server has been started.  It is not passed `req` or `res` as there is no active incoming http connection at the moment your server has just started.

`req` and `res` get passed to listeners for the [request event](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#event-request) which you can register for either by passing a callback to `http.createServer()` as in:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(res);
    res.end("hello");
});
```

Or, by registering a listener for the `request` event as in:

```
server.on('request', (req, res) => {
    console.log(res);
    res.end("hello");
});
```

---

So, it appears in your code that you just have the callbacks to `http.createServer()` and `server.listen()` **reversed**.  It's the one to `http.createServer()` that is called with `req` and `res`, not the callback to `server.listen()`.  That callback to `server.listen()` tells you when the server has been successfully started.  The callback to `http.createServer()` tells you when an incoming http request has arrived and it passes `req` and `res` to that callback.